# Exercise II 1.21.b Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, sheaf-theory

I want to show the part b) of the exercise 1.21 on sheaves in Hartshorne, that is $\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}_Y\cong i_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ with $i:Y\to X$ is the inclusion, $Y$ a closed subvariety of $X$ and $\mathcal{I}_Y$ the sheaf of ideals of $Y$.

To do so we can consider a map $\varphi_P:\mathcal{O}_{X,P}\to (i_*\mathcal{O}_Y)_P$ defined by $[U,s]\mapsto [U,s_{|U\cap Y}]$ which I do think is well defined, even if $U\cap Y=\emptyset$ for example.
Now my problem is to show it's surjective.

Take $[U,t]\in (i_*\mathcal{O}_Y)_P$ with say $P\in Y$. We have $t\in \mathcal{O}_Y(U\cap Y)$. Why would $t$ necessarily be the restriction of some section of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ ? I don't see why we could extend $t$.

Comment: What is your definition of closed subvariety?

Comment: I didn't see it on my lectures so by default I take the definition of Hartshorne for a subvariety, which I understand it to be : irreducible locally closed subset of a variety. And closed subvariety if it's closed in the variety.  I tend to think about it as a variety inside a variety, I don't know if that's misleading or not.

Comment: You are describing the topology of the subvariety. What about its structure sheaf?

Comment: The notion of structure sheaf comes a bit later doesn't it ? So I'm not sure what to answer. If it's about the sections we have $\mathcal{O}_Y(V)$ is the set of regular functions on $V$ where $V$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_Y$ is precisely the structure sheaf. of $Y$. The definition of "subvariety" should include both the topology and the "sections" (this is, how these interact with the ones corresponding to the ambient space).

Comment: So here $t$ is a regular function on $U\cap Y$ which is open in $Y$ but not necessarily in $X$, at least I think so. If it were we would have $[U\cap Y,t]\in \mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ so we would be done I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of Hartshorne chapter I, all varieties are quasi-projective (see the definition just past remark I.3.1.1), and we have the following definition of a regular map:

**Definition**. (right before remark I.3.1.1) A function $f:Y\to k$ is defined to be regular at a point $P\in Y$ if there is an open neighborhood $U$ with $P\in U\subset Y$, and homogeneous polynomials $g,h\in k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ of the same degree, such that $h$ is nowhere zero on $U$, and $f=g/h$ on $U$.

These two facts will solve our problem. Since all varieties are projective, let $Y\subset X\subset \Bbb P^n$ where $Y\subset X$ is a closed immersion. Given a $P\in Y$ and a function $f\in\mathcal{O}_{Y,P}$, select a $U\subset Y$ and $g,h\in k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ so that $f=g/h$ on $U$ as guaranteed by the definition above. Now let $U'\subset X$ be any open subset with $U'\cap Y=U$. If $h=0$ intersects $U'$, we can shrink $U'$ by removing $V(h)\cap X$, since this is a closed subset missing $P$. Now consider the regular function $g/h$ on $U'\subset X$. This restricts to our original $f$ in the map $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}\to\mathcal{O}_{Y,P}$ and we have proven surjectivity. $\blacksquare$

It's important to be a touch careful when solving this problem since many tools one would want to use haven't been introduced yet. For instance, we don't know that closed immersions are affine yet at this point in the text.

Comment: Isn't the exercise in chapter II, not chapter I?  Does the same context apply?

Comment: @Aaron from the text of the exercise: "Let $X$ be a variety over an algebraically closed field $k$, as in Ch. 1."

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of an argument. Consider the map $\varphi\colon\mathcal O_X\to i_*\mathcal O_Y$ defined by restricting to $Y$. That is, on each open set $U\subset X$, it is given by $s\mapsto s|_{Y\cap U}$. Now, check that $\varphi(s)=0$ for any $s\in \mathcal I_Y(U)$, which is essentially by definition.

Thus, we have an induced map $\varphi\colon\mathcal O_X/\mathcal I_Y\to i_*\mathcal O_Y$. We hope to show this is an isomorphism. This question is local, so assume $X$ is an affine variety and $Y$ is a closed subvariety. Then you should be able to finish from the material in Chapter I.

Comment: In fact it's precisely what I did. To show that your $\varphi$ is surjective we can show it on stalks, and if we show that my $\varphi$ is surjective we have that the maps induced by your $\varphi$ on stalks are surjective and we're done. So the missing part are the things from chapter 1. Maybe we can lift $t$ in some way but I don't know how.